# How to write SRS for a particular task/enhancement in an application

Tags: requirements, srs

I need to prepare a `Software Requirements Specification Document` for a small enhancement within an  JAVA application.

I have tried goggling for the same but found the samples for whole application whereas I am preparing SRS for a small enhancement within an application.

Can anybody suggest the links or suggestions for preparing the SRS.

Comment: Probably best on programmers SE


Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you realized by yourself what you're asked isn't a Requirements Specification, which usually covers the whole set of requirements for a software.

What you've been asked is a Change Request, and it must be merged in the existing SRS. However something tells me that there's no SRS for the software you're dealing with, as your management doesn't know the difference between both...